antd-select dropdown select options located in the top left corner of the screen are not visible, on refresh page it get fixed. in windows pc only
using antd/dist/antd.css popover and select drop down open on left top of the page in windows pc

list of options open on left of dropdown menu in antd reactjs after reload page its come below the dropdown menu which is fine
<div className="select-filter pt5 pb8">
                <Select
                  bordered={false}
                  customSelect={false}
                  showSearch
                  filterOption={(input, option: OptionsInterface) => option.label
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                  placeholder={t('common.filters.selectSubject')}
                  data={[
                    {
                      label: t('common.filters.selectSubject'),
                      value: '',
                      name: t('common.filters.selectSubject'),
                    },
                    ...(subjects ? subjects.map((subject) => ({
                      value: subject?.variant_subject_id ? subject.variant_subject_id?.join(',') : subject?.id.toString(),
                      name: subject?.name,
                      label: subject?.name,
                    })) : []),
                  ]}
                  value={filterValue?.subjectId}
                  onSelect={(value) => {
                    const subjectObj = subjectMapper[Number(value)];
                    if (subjectObj?.variant_subject_id) {
                      const variantSubject = subjectObj?.variant_subject_id?.join(',');
                      handleUpdateFilterState(variantSubject,
                        SUBJECT_ALLOCATION_CONSTANTS.SUBJECT_ID);
                    } else {
                      handleUpdateFilterState(String(value),
                        SUBJECT_ALLOCATION_CONSTANTS.SUBJECT_ID);
                    }
                    if (value) {
                      trackEvent({
                        eventType: CLICKSTREAM.EVENT_TYPES.COMMON,
                        allow: CLICKSTREAM.ALLOW,
                        name: CLICKSTREAM.EVENTS.SUBJECT_ALLOCATION.SELECT_SUBJECT_FILTER.NAME,
                        props: {
                          subject: subjects?.filter((sub) => {
                            if (sub?.variant_subject_id) {
                              return sub?.variant_subject_id?.join(',') === value?.toString();
                            }
                            return sub?.id?.toString() === value?.toString();
                          })[0]?.name || '',
                        },
                      });
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </div>


\<div class="lead-select-dropdown lead-select-dropdown-placement-bottomLeft  lead-select-dropdown-hidden" style="min-width: 180px; width: 180px; left: -949px; top: -999px;"\>



Can you try getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentElement} and it this fix the issue?

had try this not works
